# Can I use higher-order private route components inside a Switch in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to set up a `Router` to use custom `PrivateRoute` components that are equivalent to the [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) given in the official `react-router` docs. The catch is that I also want to use a catch-all 404 route, so I think I need to use a `Switch` component too, as shown in [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match) from the docs.

There's a conflict here because the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node) for `Switch` state that the children of a `Switch` component have to be `Route` components, and in [this issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4762) the team states that using non-route components inside a `Switch` is unsupported, even if it happens to work.

I've created higher-order routes and am currently using them inside a `Switch` and it seems to be working, but this won't pass code review at my company, since it's using an unsupported API that could break at any time. I want to know if there's a fully supported way to use higher-order routes together with a catch-all route.

I'm looking into trying to create a 404 route without needing to use a `Switch`, or else using regular `Route` components but wrapping the component passed to the `Route` in the authentication logic instead.

```js
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// Array of authorization functions to be tested by private routes
const authCriteria = [
  // The next route must have been referred by a previous route
  props => defined(props.location.state.from),
];

// Seems to work as expected, but violates the supported use 
// of the Switch component
const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Store} />
        <PrivateRoute 
          exact
          path='/account' 
          component={Account}
          authCriteria={authCriteria}
        />
        <PrivateRoute 
          exact
          path='/shipping' 
          component={Shipping} 
          authCriteria={authCriteria}
        />
        <PrivateRoute 
          exact 
          path='/checkout' 
          component={Checkout} 
          authCriteria={authCriteria}
        />
        // Catch-all route means we need to use a Switch
        <Route render={() => (<h2>Not Found</h2>)} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: You want to make a "Default" (404) route, but without using a `Switch`?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I think you need the switch because the last route of the switch should be the `default` route (eg: 404). The way the `Switch` works is that if the path doesn't match any previous routes, it will render the last route. Without the `Switch` component, you'll always have the 404 component rendered.

Comment: How is the `Switch` an unsupported API? [Switch Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)

Comment: @technogeek1995 using non-route components as children of the `Switch` is unsupported. [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node)

Comment: @KevinWaddle I understand now. I think I created what you're asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
I changed my route authentication HoC to wrap the component rendered by the route, not the route itself. The first answer that was posted would probably be better if the authentication criteria were static, but the app I'm working on is an order placement workflow where access to different routes can depend on different factors, like having completed or come from other routes, so I needed to be able to pass arbitrary authentication criteria to each route.

Here's the code that shows the `withAuth` HoC I used to wrap each component and how it works with the router:

```js
// Test every passed-in auth verification function.
const verifyAuth = (authCriteria, props) => {
  if (authCriteria.length === 0) return true;
  return authCriteria.every(criterion => criterion(props));
};

// Authentication HoC
const withAuth = ({
  authCriteria = [],
  redirectPath = '/',
} = {}) => Component => props => {
  const isAuthorized = verifyAuth(authCriteria, props);
  return (
    isAuthorized ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect 
        to={{ 
          pathname: redirectPath, 
          state: { from: props.location },
        }} 
      />
    )
  );
};

// TODO: authenticate user
const validUser = _props => true; 
// The next route must have been referred by a previous route
const internalReferral = props => defined(props.location.state);

// The Store route has different authentication requirements
// than the other two routes 
const storeCriteria = [validUser];
const mainCriteria = [validUser, internalReferral];

const authRoute = withAuth({ authCriteria: mainCriteria });

const ProtectedRoutes = {
  Store: withAuth({ authCriteria: storeCriteria })(Store),
  Shipping: authRoute(Shipping),
  Checkout: authRoute(Checkout),
};

const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={ProtectedRoutes.Store} />
        <Route exact path='/shipping' component={ProtectedRoutes.Shipping} />
        <Route exact path='/checkout' component={ProtectedRoutes.Checkout} />
        <Route render={() => (<h2>Not Found</h2>)} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question's links to react-router's github, it doesn't appear like you can use a HOC inside a `Switch`.

However, you can achieve something similar. Basically, you need two routers. The first `Router` routes all pre-authenticated routes, like logging in, new users, password forgot, etc. Since it's inside a `Switch`, it should render your second `Router`. Your second `Router` will contain all your authentication required routes. However, you need to include a conditional check to make sure the user is authenticated. If the user isn't authenticated, you can just return a `Redirect` back to the `/login` path. This works because of the first `Switch`. If the user goes to a url that isn't available to unauthenticated users, the user will always get redirected to the `/login` since they will hit the default condition in the first switch and the `Redirect` of the second component.

```
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppRouter = (props) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/new-user' component={CreateAccount} />
        <Route render={props => <AuthenticationRouter {...props} />}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

const AuthenticatedRouter = (props) => {
  if( props.userIsAuthenticated ) {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Store} />
          <Route 
            exact
            path='/account' 
            component={Account}
          />
          <Route 
            exact
            path='/shipping' 
            component={Shipping} 
          />
          <Route 
            exact 
            path='/checkout' 
            component={Checkout} 
          />
          <Route render={() => (<h2>Not Found</h2>)} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: "/login",
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This solution would have worked for me if I were using the same criteria to authenticate every route, but for what I'm building I needed to be able to provide different authentication criteria to different routes. I ended up making an HoC to wrap components, instead of `Route`s, and posted my solution.